# prove that language is not decidable (string and reverse)

Tags: turing-machines

Prove that $T=\{\langle M\rangle\mid M \text{ is TM that accepts $w^R$ iff it accepts $w$}\} $ is not decidable. I have no idea how to start. Help me, please

Comment: Rice's theorem, maybe?  (But I'm very rusty on this stuff.) ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Yes, It may helps me. Is there solution without this theorem ?